# How do I get useEffect to run when using React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm working on building a react app based on a REST API for practice and I cannot figure out why my useEffect function is never running and therefore `item` is never getting set. I am working on an Inventory Management application. Here is my code:

*Item.jsx:*

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
 
function Item() {
  const [item, setItem] = useState({});
  const id = useParams().id || 0;
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Fetching");
    fetch(`http://localhost:8080/item/${id}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setItem(data["Items"]);
      });
    console.log("Fetched");
  }, [id]);
 
  return (
    <div key={id}>
      <h1 className="">{item["name"]}</h1>
      <h2 className="px-3">Quantity: {item["quantity"]}</h2>
      <h2 className="px-3">Price: ${item["price"].toFixed(2)}</h2>
      <h2 className="px-3">Description: {item["description"]}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Item;
```

*Index.js*:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./Components/App";
import Item from "./Components/Item";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="container">
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<App />} />
        <Route path="/item/:id" element={<Item />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Full Repository [here](https://github.com/bgoldstone/go-inventory-rest/tree/master/frontend/src).

Comment: It should be `const id = useParams().id || 0;` instead of `const id = useParams().id | 0;`.

Comment: `const { id = 0 } = useParams()` might be the preferred method. I don't see any possible why for the `useEffect` hook's callback ***not*** to be called when the `id` value changes. At-a-minimum, the `useEffect` hook is invoked *at least* once when the component mounts. What or where is the `id` route path param generated? Can you update you post to include all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

Some problems could arise from defaulting the item `id` when making use of the `useParams` hook.

It would be safer to keep the `id` undefined and then inside your `useEffect` make use off a guard statement like this:

```
const { id } = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  if (id === undefined) return; // stops running  if `id` isn't defined
  ... // add fetch statement here
}, [id])
```

Now you will successfully prevent fetching before `id` is defined.

Comment: return in useEffect commonly used for clean-up purposes. although the code will working maybe it is better to wrap the fetch statement inside `if (id) {  fetch statement } `  ?

Comment: If you return nothing it does the same thing…